# Display image in Gridview column, column needs to be created dynamically

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I need to display an image within a GridView control. The column creation needs to be dynamic. In other words the entire column creation needs to be done within the code.

Lots of postings refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx. The problem is that I need the columns to be created dynamically, since I don't know in advance if the image column would display. Also, that article may be old since its still referencing asp.net version 2.0. I'm developing it in vs2010 which I believe uses asp.net version 3.5 (or greater)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a truly dynamic grid, then you can build your grid in code. It's a little tricky but not impossible. Here is a self contained example which you can take a look at.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

    class MyItemTemplate : System.Web.UI.ITemplate
    {

        public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
        {
            Label label = new Label();
            label.ID = "MyLabel";
            container.Controls.Add(label);
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv;
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            gv = new GridView();
            gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            gv.ID = "MyGrid";
            var column = new TemplateField();
            column.HeaderText = "My Item";
            column.ItemTemplate = new MyItemTemplate();
            gv.Columns.Add(column);
            MyDiv.Controls.Add(gv);
            gv.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gv_RowDataBound);
        }

        var dataSource = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
        gv = this.Page.FindControl("MyGrid") as GridView;

        gv.DataSource = dataSource;
        gv.DataBind();
    }

    void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var label = e.Row.FindControl("MyLabel") as Label;
        if (label != null)
            label.Text = ((string)e.Row.DataItem).ToUpper();
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="MyDiv" runat="server">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. TWO ISSUES 1) It’s the columns that should be dynamically created. The actual GridView should be fixed and created in the standard way.
2) I need to display an image within a cell

Comment: 1) this example dynamically creates a column 2) the column you create could have a placeholder where you add an image.

Comment: sure... let me put something together.. let me ask you.. would it be easier for you to have a standard grid and just hide and show columns based on the data? what exactly is dynamic about it? Maybe we're overcomplicating it?

Comment: If it’s easier to display data in a standard-grid, then let’s go for it. My data is dynamic in the sense that every other row is text, and the other row is an image, but the total number of columns is NOT fixed. In  other words the even column numbers are images and the odd column numbers is text. If I have to hardcode the number of columns to 15 or so, then I’ll accept that. Simplicity is important.

Comment: what does the data source look like?

Comment: It’s stored in a list, but I would like to assign the data directly, not via binding. Anyway the images have to be manually assigned, since they are located in a file. should this be moved to a chat? anyway I have to leave. THANKS again

Comment: Eric Thanks. I used your suggestions....partially. I'm still using the GridView. I'm toggling between displaying/hiding a fix number of columns.